# C# Method return MysqlDataReader result (returning a List with 2 or more values)

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying to make a method. So I will be able to get result of a queryText. But using `Dictionary` not an option since key has to be unique which in some cases it is not.

The idea is that i should be able to do something like this:

```
var storeQuery = StoreQuery(query);
storeQuery["first_name"] or storeQuery["last_name"]
```

```
public Dictionary<string, object> StoreQuery(string queryText)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> queryDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    using (MySqlConnection connection = CreateConnection())
    {
        using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(queryText, connection))
        {
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        queryDictionary.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader.GetValue(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return queryDictionary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you stated yourself you can't have a `Dictionary` with keys which are not unique, so both options in my answer assumes you need first occurance of the key:

Option 1: using `List` of `Tuple`s

```
    public List<Tuple<string, string>> StoreQuery(string queryText)
    {
        List<Tuple<string, string>> queryList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
        using (MySqlConnection connection = CreateConnection())
        {
            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(queryText, connection))
            {
                using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            queryList.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader.GetValue(i));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return queryList;
    }
```

Usage:

```
        var storeQuery = StoreQuery(query);
        storeQuery.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x.Item1, "first_name"));//this will return first oocurance of "first_name" as a key
```

Option 2: using `List` of `KeyValuePair`s:

```
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> StoreQuery(string queryText)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queryList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        using (MySqlConnection connection = CreateConnection())
        {
            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(queryText, connection))
            {
                using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            queryList.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader.GetValue(i));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return queryList;
    }
```

Usage:

```
        var storeQuery = StoreQuery(query);
        storeQuery.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x.Key, "first_name"));//this will return first oocurance of "first_name" as a key
```